# Error in running the "margins" function in R

Tags: r, regression, marginal-effects

I have built a simple lm model as shown below:

```
model1 = lm(score ~
   study_hours +
   courses_taken +
   study_hours:courses_taken +
   taken_before +
   mediumenjoyment +
   highenjoyment +
   female,
   data = course_data)
```

now, I'm trying to compute the marginal effect at the means. So, my code for doing so is:

```
mean_list = data.frame(mean(score),
                       mean(study_hours),
                       mean(courses_taken),
                       mean(study_hours:courses_taken),
                       mean(taken_before),
                       mean(mediumenjoyment),
                       mean(highenjoyment),
                       mean(female))


mar2 = margins(model1, data = mean_list)

summary(mar2)
```

But when I run the code, this error is raised:

```
Error in mean(score) : object 'score' not found
```

Comment: You didn't include the error, or your data.

Comment: first of all what is `mean(study_hours:courses_taken)`???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KU99 its an interaction term in the model

Comment: in that case try `margins(model1, data.frame(t(colMeans(model1$model))))`

Comment: Only because you hae numeric data. Otherwise it is not generic. The idea you present is quite confusing to be honest. Note that `margins(model1, model1$model)` should also work. But the result will be bit different

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the error is in this line:

```r
mean(study_hours:courses_taken)
```

Typically, object names in `R` do not include colons, so I imagine that you can’t take the mean.

In passing, I’ll note that the `margins` package works great in many cases, but that it is not actively being developed. You could [try the newer `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (disclaimer: I am the author). That package allows you to compute marginal effects at the mean ([documentation](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/mfx.html#marginal-effect-at-the-mean-mem)) easily by typing:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
mfx <- marginaleffects(mod, newdata = datagrid())
summary(mfx)
#> Average marginal effects 
#>    Term   Effect Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    2.5 %   97.5 %
#> 1   cyl -0.11144    1.04502 -0.1066 0.915075 -2.15964  1.93676
#> 2  disp  0.01334    0.01786  0.7468 0.455209 -0.02166  0.04834
#> 3    hp -0.02148    0.02177 -0.9868 0.323717 -0.06415  0.02118
#> 4  drat  0.78711    1.63537  0.4813 0.630301 -2.41816  3.99238
#> 5    wt -3.71530    1.89441 -1.9612 0.049857 -7.42829 -0.00232
#> 6  qsec  0.82104    0.73083  1.1234 0.261255 -0.61137  2.25345
#> 7    vs  0.31776    2.10451  0.1510 0.879982 -3.80700  4.44252
#> 8    am  2.52023    2.05665  1.2254 0.220423 -1.51073  6.55119
#> 9  gear  0.65541    1.49326  0.4389 0.660724 -2.27132  3.58215
#> 10 carb -0.19942    0.82875 -0.2406 0.809845 -1.82374  1.42491
#> 
#> Model type:  lm 
#> Prediction type:  response
```